# Page Expands Unintentionally

Tags: html, resize, width

I have been working on a website for my self recently and ran into an odd problem. Whenever I would move a  to the left the page would expand by the amount of pixels I had moved it left from the center. It doesn't hinder functionality but it's really annoying to have this 300-400 pixel space that you can scroll off to the side with. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of what I am doing:

```
<html> 
<body style="background-image: url('Background-Large.jpg'); text-align: center">
<div style="position:relative;top: -605px; left: 295px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your DIV is set:

```
left: 295px;
```

If you want a DIV to be in the center the first thing you should do is make a "main container":

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {width:500px;margin:0 auto -1.5em;}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Then from there you can add elements inside that container thats now centered:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div style="float:left;margin-left:-295px;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is because I would like it to be 295px from the center of the page.

Comment: Is there a way to move it without the page resizing?

Comment: Is that full code? I ask becuase if youre jsut showing 1 DIV it's impossible for me to tell you why it's acting the way it is without the other elements to share relationship.

Comment: @HarrySlotwiner http://www.css3.com/css-left/ `left` doesn't origin from the center.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here but if you put an 'overflow:hidden' on the body, it should allow you to position your div off the page without adding a scroll bar.